# Como excluir todos os arquivos de um diretório

Tags: c#

Gostaria de saber como faço para deletar todos os arquivos de um diretório.

Suponhamos que eu precise deletar todos os arquivos da pasta Teste em C:\teste.

Comment: Não precisa adicionar `[Resolvido]` no final do post. Basta apenas aceitar uma resposta que o sistema já marca sua publicação como "resolvida".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Conforme [resposta em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288718/how-to-delete-all-files-and-folders-in-a-directory):

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("YourPath");

foreach (FileInfo file in di.GetFiles())
{
    file.Delete(); 
}
foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in di.GetDirectories())
{
    dir.Delete(true); 
}
```

ou

```
System.IO.Directory.Delete(@"C:\Temp", true);
```

ou

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
var directory = Directory.GetParent(TestContext.TestDir);

directory.EnumerateFiles()
    .ForEachInEnumerable(f => f.Delete());

directory.EnumerateDirectories()
    .ForEachInEnumerable(d => d.Delete(true));
```

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado!